# Missing character off incoming string from Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, arduino, bluetooth

I am currently trying to create a water level readout as a progress bar in a simple Android app. Currently, I am using an Arduino Mega 2560 with a HC-05 to transmit the readout of the water level sensor. To simplify things, the arduino code is just counting up and down from 0 to 1000 and back, as follows.

```
    void setup() {
      // put your setup code here, to run once:
      Serial.begin(9600);
      Serial.println("Test for Water Sensor");
      Serial1.begin(9600);
    
    }
    
    void loop() {
      // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    
      for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
      {
        Serial1.println(i);
        Serial.println(i);
        delay(100);
      }
      for (int i = 1000; i >= 0; i--)
      {
        Serial1.println(i);
        Serial.println(i);
        delay(100);
      }
    }
```

On the android end, I am using this to convert to int, then change the progress bar. It also currently displays the unconverted message in a TextView.

```
      mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                if(msg.what == MESSAGE_READ){
                    String readMessage = null;
                    try {
                        readMessage = new String((byte[]) msg.obj, "UTF-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mReadBuffer.setText(readMessage);
                    try {
                        waterLevelValue = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(readMessage).intValue();
                        waterLevel.setProgress(waterLevelValue);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if(msg.what == CONNECTING_STATUS){
                    if(msg.arg1 == 1)
                        mBluetoothStatus.setText("Connected to Device: " + msg.obj);
                    else
                        mBluetoothStatus.setText("Connection Failed");
                }
            }
        };
```

The issue I am getting is that quite often (maybe 1-2 times a second) it is not reading the first digit. I can see on the Serial Monitor that all digits are going there, but on the android app, it will sometimes miss the first (eg: 443, 444, 45, 446, 447, etc)

What could be causing the issue here, I am very new to Bluetooth, so please help! More than happy to send more portions of code if needed.

EDIT:  Adding code for reading input stream. Probably was important in the first place.

```
public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()
            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.available();
                    if(bytes != 0) {
                        SystemClock.sleep(100); //pause and wait for rest of data. Adjust this depending on your sending speed.
                        bytes = mmInStream.available(); // how many bytes are ready to be read?
                        bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, bytes); // record how many bytes we actually read
                        mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                                .sendToTarget(); // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you send the data to early in the Arduino ? may send some data before the bluetooth connected .  could try to  delay more time before send data in  Arduino.

Comment: I posted the whole Arduino code, I could try putting the delay before the Serial.println() and see if that helps.
EDIT: It did not help

Comment: You would get more response if the question would contain the necessary code parts. Currently the Java part is incomplete, it es e.g. not clear where `msg.obj` comes from.

Comment: Every instance of msg in my code is in the java code block I have posted here. I will add code to where MESSAGE_READ comes from, that might be what you are after.

Comment: Just a thought I just had, I could potentially store the last 10 incoming figures, then have it remove any too far from the average, then average out the rest. Eg: 543, 555, 548, 47, 555, 587, 540, 53, 567, 580. avg is 457.8 take away 47, 53, as too far out of avg, new avg is 559, then use that for waterLevel. I don't need this data to be 100% accurate, so if this is +-5% I would get away with it. Would this work?